# Spreadsheet and address: how to filter based on a range

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of entries. I need to extract some data from it based on the content of another spreadsheet.

The file looks like this:

```
   ID    Location   Address

------   ------  ------------

000001   London   Oxford St.

000002   London   Ladbroke Sq.

000003   London   Beryl Rd.
...       ...        ...
```

On a second sheet I have a list of address. What I need to do is to filter the content of the first sheet based on the address I listed.

I thought `ARRAYFORMULA` could the the work but I'm stuck with this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(((Sample!$A:$A)=$A2) * ((Sample!$B:$B)=B$1) * (Sample!$C:$C) ))
```

Comment: Where are addresses on the second sheet (which column)? Is that the only info in that sheet?

Comment: Please post a complete set of sample input, and expected output.

Comment: on the second sheet I have just a list of address. Ie: based on the sample above I have just Oxfort St. and Beryl Rd. The expect output on the first sheet should then be the filter of the ID number 000001 and 00003.

Answer (score 0):

If your data on the first sheet looked something like this:
[image]

**One option** would be `INDEX(MATCH())` on the second sheet:
[image]

**Another option** - creating a separate column for filtering in the first sheet:
[image]

Too bad conditional formatting formulas do not work when they take references from another sheet.